# jQuery plugin, when the last init has fired?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-plugins

Given the following jQuery plugin code:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

var pluginName = 'myPluginName';

// Create the plugin constructor
function Plugin ( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this._defaults = $.fn.myPluginName.defaults;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, this._defaults, options );

    this.init();
}

// Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
$.extend(Plugin.prototype, {

    // Initialization logic
    init: function () {
    },

});

$.fn.myPluginName = function ( options ) {
    this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    });
    return this;
};

$.fn.myPluginName.defaults = {
    property: 'value',
    onComplete: null
};

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Every instance of the plugin goes within a init function. Is there a way to know when the last init has been fired? That mean when the final instance has been initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the last initilization of an element if you run through all the elements with jQuery's $.each() meathod, like so :-

First you store the `length of the elements` - 1 and then you check if the current element being iterated over has an index that matches the `length of the elements` - 1. if so , its the last initialization !

```js
AddBg = ($elem) => {
  $elem.css({
    'background-color' : 'red'
  })
}

let initElemLength = $('div').length - 1;

$('div').each(function(i , e) {
  AddBg($(this));
  if(i === initElemLength) { console.log('Last initilization Done!') }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 10vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The logic is right indeed, but I am having some trouble to apply this logic on the architecture of a jQuery plugin as mentioned in my first post.
As the init function isn't executed directly into the each loop.